# Honeywell TH6110D1005 Thermostat keeps resetting itself

Tags: thermostat

I have a Honeywell TH6110D1005 thermostat. I do not use the program mode, I keep my temp set to 71° at all times when it is on the Cool setting.

Sometimes, it resets itself to 65° for no reason whatsoever. I have replaced the batteries with new red Duracells but it happened again.

It is intermittent and it can go weeks without doing this.

I can't figure out why it is happening.

Comment: Can you provide the thermostat with a C wire from the 24VAC transformer?

Comment: I am really not that sure. I don't know if the transformer is actually hooked up.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring configuration at the 'stat and at the HVAC unit?